# SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("/combinedcerts.cer") failed

Tags: nginx

I'm getting an error, the "combinedcerts.cer" is present but unable to locate the certificate, this is error i'm getting

nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("/combinedcerts.cer") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory

"COPY files/certs/ca.cer files/certs/rivaterootca.cer files/certs/combinedcerts.cer files/conf/useragent.rules files/keystore.jks ./" Docker files
can someone help to fix this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.